# Using Split and discard later characters in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
http://localhost:3000/myname
http://localhost:3000/myname#&gid=1&pid=1
```

I'm able to get `myname` using `location.href.split('/')[3];` but the second url failed. How to have an extra logic that discard starting the # and the following characters?

Answer (score 2):

You want to get only the path component of the location?

That doesn't need split or other string operations, because all the work has been done for you already: [`location.pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/pathname)

(Ok, not *all* the work, if you don't want the leading slash. But that should be trivial to get rid of, using substr(ing) or whatever.)

---

Edit: You're asking in comments, if it will "still work" if you had `localhost:3000/myname/a/b/c`. Well first of all that depends, on what you actually *need to it do*, to consider it "working." Your original question wasn't clear on that - next time, try and include such cases and expected outcome in the question as well please.

If you need all the folder names out of the path separately, then you can still use split - but use it on location.pathname, then you don't have to deal with a hash. And since the value starts with a slash, and that will produce an empty first element in the split result, you might just want to throw that one away, using Array.shift:

```
var pathparts = location.pathname.split('/');
pathparts.shift();
console.log(pathparts);
```

Comment: Depends - what result do you expect/want in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a combination of `replace()` and `slice()`

```
var temp_name = location.href.replace(/http:\/\/localhost:3000\//, "");

var my_name = temp_name.match(/#/) ? temp_name.slice(0, temp_name.indexOf("#")) : temp_name;
```

The trick here is that you only slice the temp_name if a hashtag is present.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `location.href.substring(0, location.href.indexOf('#'));`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the anchor element and then the [hostname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/hostname).

```js
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href='http://localhost:3000/myname/a/b/c/?gid=1&pid=1#hash'
console.log(a.host);
console.log(a.hostname);
console.log(a.pathname);
console.log(a.search);
console.log(a.hash);
```

Comment: I use split because I also have route like localhost:3000/myname/a/b/c

Answer (score 0):

Or just basicaly in vanillia:

```
var string = "http://localhost:3000/myname#&gid=1&pid=1";
var result = string.split('/')[3].split("#")[0];
console.log(result); // myname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var m = /\/(.[^#]*)/.exec(location.pathname);
var result = m ? m[1] : "";
```